# Unable to add row in the middle of jQuery datatables(with FIDDLE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to add new rows to the table using the `rows.add()` function in the `DataTables` API. The data is coming from the server using `AJAX` call.

Here is an example to work upon - [FIDDLE](http://live.datatables.net/buciqaye/1/)

My Table Structure is follows:

```
    <table id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <th>
                Id
            </th>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Designation
            </th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @item.Number
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.Name
                        <img id="imgA" onclick="AddNewRows();" class="iterationChild" src="@Url.Content("~/Images/plus.png")" alt="expand/collapse" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.Designation
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Corresponding Javascript function:

```
function AddNewRows() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("NewRows", "Home")',
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();

            for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
            //how to add it just after the current row clicked
              table.row.add([
                   data[i].Number,
                   data[i].Name,
                   data[i].Designation
              ]).draw();
            }
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
}
```

I want to be able to add the new row after the row which is clicked. Here it is adding at the end of the table(last rows).

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html

Comment: @JuanC....managed to add rows but not directly after the click. updated my question

Comment: any assistance here...?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming every row as a unique id, try passing the current row clicked id into your function as a parameter. Example:
function AddNewRows(id) {
 var my_row = document.getElementById(id);
...